# Is there a "function-like-thing" that can act as a template?

Tags: powershell

I have a code like this that is repeated multiple times in each of my conditional statements/cases. i have 3 conditions...for now, and everything works perfectly, but im mulling reformatting the script for easier reading.

One of the ways ive thought is to make a function, but the problem is that, i have a while loop that is intended for a specific scenario in each conditional statement that dequeues from a Queue containing some column names from a file.

so based on the code below that i want to put in some sort of template, i cant think of how this could work because as you can see, $tb stands for $table, which is what im opening prior to the conditional statements in my code. 
if i were to include everything regarding the server connection and table in a function, that means when i pass the "function" containing the code to the while loops, it will be creating/instantiating the table every iteration, which wont make sense and wont work anyways.

so i am thinking of using something like annotations, something like a template which wont expect to return anything or need reasonable arguments like a function otherwise would. The question is, does something like that exist?

This is the code that is the same across all my while loops that i would like to "store" somewhere and just pass it to them:

```
$dqHeader = $csvFileHeadersQueue.Dequeue()

$column = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb, $dqHeader, $DataType1)

if ($dqHeader -in $PrimaryKeys)
{
    # We require a primary key.

    $column.Nullable = $false
    #$column.Identity = $true #not needed with VarChar
    #$column.IdentitySeed = 1 #not needed with VarChar
    $tb.Columns.Add($column)

    $primaryKey = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index($tb, "PK_$csvFileBaseName")
    $primaryKey.IndexType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.IndexType]::ClusteredIndex
    $primaryKey.IndexKeyType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.IndexKeyType]::DriPrimaryKey #Referential Integrity to prevent data inconsistency. Changes in primary keys must be updated in foreign keys.
    $primaryKey.IndexedColumns.Add((New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.IndexedColumn($primaryKey, $dqHeader)))
    $tb.Indexes.Add($primaryKey)
}
else
{
    $tb.Columns.Add($column)
}
```

think of it like a puzzle piece that would fit right in when requested to do so in the while loops to complete that "puzzle"

Comment: I think you need explain more about the general setup, why can't you just use a normal `Function` (variables should be available for reading, and objects are usually referenced anyway), does concern (remote) jobs, multi-threading? Try to build a [mcve] of what you want to achieve. In general, I think your answer is in [About Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7) `$Global:csvFileHeadersQueue = ...`???

Comment: @iRon i know its kinda vague, but my script is like 600 LOC which is not feasible to post here. Really the main point behind this is to reduce the LOC by somehow making this piece of code i posted into a "template" that i can just plug in where this current code exists throughout the script. I think scope might be it, ill take a look into that. basically think of it like `$template = @"code in post goes here"@` and i would just pass $template inside the while loops wherever necessary/wherever this code already exists and replace it with it.

Comment: I think you looking into the wrong direction, Anyways, you can share a (hardcoded) `[ScriptBlock]` (`$template = {code in post goes here}`) with a `While` loop (or function) and invoke it with e.g. `Invoke-Command $template`. Dynamically modifying it and using commands like `Invoke-Expression` or `[ScriptBlock]::Create()` is not a good idea due to risk of malicious code injections. See: [Rule for the use of the command: ScriptBlock::Create #1454](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1454#issue-603433584)

Comment: @iRon interesting, im not planning to modify the code in the $template since I do intend for it be hardcoded just like that. Though, what would be some ways a modification syntax would look like? I'll try that out, thanks!

Comment: @iRon For example, let's say everything is the same except $DataType1. Is that something I can specifically modify as part of invoke? If so, would it be like Invoke-Expression $template.modify(replace ”$DataType1” ”$DataType2”)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment:
you can share a (hardcoded) [ScriptBlock] (`$template = {code in post goes here}`) with a While loop (or function) and invoke it with e.g. `Invoke-Command $template` or the call operator: `&$template`. Dynamically modifying an expression and using commands like `Invoke-Expression` or `[ScriptBlock]::Create()` is not a good idea due to risk of malicious code injections (see: [#1454](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1454#issue-603433584)).

You might even add parameters to your shared `[ScriptBlock]`, like:

```
$Template = {
    [CmdletBinding()]Param ($DataType)
    $column = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb, $dqHeader, $DataType)
    ...
}

ForEach ($MyDataType in @('MyDataType')) {
    Invoke-Command $Template -ArgumentList $MyDataType
}
```

But the counter-question remains: ***Why not just creating a  ["helper"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270178/what-are-helper-functions-in-c) function?***:

```
Function template($DataType) {
    $column = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb, $dqHeader, $DataType)
    ...
}

ForEach ($MyDataType in @('MyDataType')) {
    template $MyDataType
}
```

Comment: dude, i was overthinking it! i just created a function and passed in the table instance and its working perfectly! sometimes, i just blank out lol. then again ive been programming this script for the last 5 days straight nonstop, my brain is FRIED!